# GA4: Filter Events Based On User ID

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I am using GTM to track users and traffic on my website with GA4. My goal is to exclude traffic from internal users but all the information I find about that topic is around filtering based on IP addresses. As everyone is distributed geographically working from home, I wanted to set it up to filter by the user ID which is already being tracked.

I read about having to set `debug_mode` or `debug_event` to `true` and enabling the debug traffic filter in GA4. For the `debug_mode` variable, I set up a lookup table like this:

[image]
[image]

As I said, I am already tracking the user ID, so I know the `{{ User ID }}` part to work. Finally, I made this configuration to send `debug_mode` to GA4:

[image]

The problem is: When I open the website I am seeing the events in GA4's Debug View without going through "Preview" of GTM, BUT I am also seeing it in the realtime dashboard.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set up `debug_mode` is true. This would only allow you to see more detail data in the `debug_view`. It will also show in the `Realtime Report`

This is not the way you want to exclude certain users.

---

Now we can only create a trigger and except it on every GA4 trigger you used. This might take some time but we can only wait for Google to release a better and faster way to manage it.

[image]